# voice.play() параметр after вызывается в начале проигрывания аудио

Tags: python, discord.py

Параметр after вызывается в начале проигрывания

Бот присоединяется и сразу отключается

Вот код команды:

```
@bot.command(name='play')
async def play(ctx):
    voice = await ctx.message.author.voice.channel.connect()
    voice.play(source=discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg.exe", source = 'audio.mp3'), after=await voice.disconnect())
```

UPD:

При передаче функции возникает ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 686, in _call_after
    self.after(error)
TypeError: disconnect() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: `after=voice.disconnect`, не вызывайте функцию, а передайте её

Comment: @CrazyElf Говорит что disconnect получает 2 аргумента
`TypeError: disconnect() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`